# Java Regular expression Set Minimum characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm new in using regex in java and now having problems getting my regular expression working. 
I want to keep **minimum 3 characters** in a string, if it only 2 characters, i want to delete it.

**here's my string :**

```
It might be more sensible for real users if I also included a lower limit on the number of letters.
```

**The output i want :**

```
might more sensible for real users also includedlower limit the number letters.
```

So, i did some googling but still doesnt work.
so basically here's the complete code (1-5 is the regex i've tried):

```
String input = "It might be more sensible for real users if I also included a lower limit on the number of letters.";
    //1. /^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/
    //2. /^[a-zA-Z]{3,30}$/
    //3. \\b[a-zA-Z]{4,30}\\b
    //4.  ^\\W*(?:\\w+\\b\\W*){3,30}$
    //5. [+]?(?:[a-zA-Z]\\s*){3,30}

    String output = input.replaceAll("/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/", ""); 
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Do you have to use a regex?

Comment: my teacher recommended me to do so, but if you have a better and faster answer, please let me know.

Comment: You could use String[] words = input.split(" "); and then check each word in the array for its length using length().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
package com.stackoverflow.answer;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "It might be more sensible for real users if I also included a lower limit on the number of letters.";
        System.out.println("BEFORE: " + input);
        input = input.replaceAll("\\b[\\w']{1,2}\\b", "").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
        System.out.println("AFTER: " + input);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\\w{1,3}` to get any 1-2 word characters. You then need to make sure they are not adjacent to other word characters before removing them, so you check for non-word characters (`\\W`) and beginning or ending of the line (`^` and `$`) like so:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(^|\\W)\\w{1,3}($|\\W)", " ");
```

Note the extra space cleans up for the potentially 2 spaces we are removing.